# What is the right redirect uri for OpenIDConenct in flutter?

Tags: flutter, redirect, openid, openid-connect

I'm using the [openid_connect](https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client) package in flutter 1.20.2.

What should I write in the redirect uri section of this api?

```
final authenticator = Authenticator(client,
          scopes: scopes, , urlLancher: urlLauncher, redirectUri: '???');
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common and simplest option for mobile OAuth is a private URI scheme value such as this:

- com.mycompany.myapp:/callback

If you are more ambitious you can use a Claimed Https Scheme, such as this:

- https://mobile.mycompany.com/myapp/callback

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

Browsing a couple of visual blog posts of mine may help you understand how this looks. I am not using Flutter, but the OAuth concepts will be the same:

- [AppAuth Sample with Private URI Scheme](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup)
- [Advanced Sample with Claimed HTTPS Scheme](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/22/ios-code-sample-overview)